Facebook Developer : Privacy policy url error while changing an app back to Live mode
My app was already live in facebook. I had then changed it back to "In development" , to integrate instagram. Although i did spend some time, i did not request for any new permission. I reverted any changes i had done to my developer account. The only change which i cannot revert is to remove Instagram from "Products" in my app.
My privacy policy url was always : https://hype.workflowlabsfusion.com/privacypolicy/index.html
It is accessible. Now when i try to change it to In development mode, facebook keeps giving the error
You must provide a valid Privacy Policy URL in order take your app Live. Go to Basic Settings and make sure it is valid.

But my url is very much accessible, there is no change in content of the privacy policy. What is possibly going wrong ? I have been trying to resolve this from the past 2 days.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

According to Facebook's URL debugger, they are getting a status code 418 from your system, when requesting that URL - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fhype.workflowlabsfusion.com%2Fprivacypolicy%2Findex.html  Couldn't tell you why (I'm getting 200 OK when I go to your URL in my browser) - but you'll have to figure it out and fix it, otherwise Facebook will not consider this a valid privacy policy URL.
